# Issue with accessing a REST API

Tags: python, api, rest

I get a response from:
https://mmtest-directory.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/mm/v1/rest

However,  within my main.py:

```
service = build('mmtest-directory', 'v1', discoveryServiceUrl=settings.discovery_uri)
```

is throwing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mytasks\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    service = build('mmtest-directory', 'v1', discoveryServiceUrl=settings.discovery_uri)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'discovery_uri'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `settings` module has no member `discovery_uri`. I suggest you set such a variable.

Comment: That was it.  I added the appropriate statement in my settings.py, and that solved the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: @DonD You're welcome. The python error messages are very informative, and should generally be taken as literally true.